# Call Sub to copy to destination only pasting fragment of data, works as intended when just running Sub

Tags: excel, vba

any help appreciated with this issue.

My first post here, feel free to let me know if I can make the post better!

The gist is:

I have the overarching sub (DataTool) that loops through a list of codes, for these codes it filters three sheets each with raw data, then a sub copies the filtered data from each sheet to a template workbook, names the template workbook with the code, saves it, reopens the template and goes onto the next code.

The issue occurs when copying the filtered data from identified range in the DataTool to the intended range template workbook. (I am not getting entire rows or columns as there are formulas on the template surrounding where I place the data.)

The issue is when the sub that copies the data to the template pastes it into the template it is not pasting all of it to the destination, it just sort of randomly cuts off.

I have tried copy to dest row by row, and cell by cell (highly inefficient) and still end up with random cut offs. The source data is in rows well beyond 50,000 so I dim rownum as Long (I heard something about a 16bit 32,000 row cut off for Integer).

Deidentified code below. I don't think I can add the actual files because the data can't be deidentified.

```
    Sub MainSub()

'this is the list of codes it runs through
NumRows = Workbooks(DataTool). _
Sheets("FLOATING"). _
Range("E2:E17"). _
Rows.Count

'loop through codes
For i = 1 To NumRows

CodeStr = _
Workbooks(DataTool). _
Sheets("FLOATING"). _
Range("E" & i + 1).Value

CodeTranslation = _
Workbooks(DataTool). _
Sheets("FLOATING"). _
Range("F" & i + 1).Value

'I thought it might be a maximum range selected issue _
so I added this to select "a1" on all sheets
Call reduceselectALL(DataTool)

DoEvents

Call sourcerange1loop(DataTool, CodeStr)

DoEvents

MsgBox "did events", vbOKOnly

Call sourcerange2loop(DataTool, CodeStr)

DoEvents

Call sourcerange3loop(DataTool, CodeTranslation)

DoEvents

'Label Workbook with CodeTranslation
Workbooks("01 Master Template.xlsm"). _
Sheets("Sickleave"). _
Range("A1").Value = CodeTranslation

'Save & Close

Workbooks("01 Master Template.xlsm").SaveAs _
MasterSavePath & "\" & CodeTranslation & " Report.xlsm"

Workbooks(CodeTranslation & " Report.xlsm").Close True

Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1").ShowAllData
Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange2").ShowAllData
Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange3").ShowAllData

Application.Workbooks.Open (MasterSavePath & "\01 Master Template.xlsm")
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next

End Sub

Sub sourcerange1loop(DataTool As String, sourcerange1 As String)

'Filter sourcerange1 in DataTool
Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1").Range( _
Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(1, 9).Address).AutoFilter _
Field:=8, Criteria1:=CodeStr 

'Send sourcerange1 to template post filter in Loop

Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1").Range( _
Cells(2, 1).Address, Cells(2, 9).End(xlDown).Address).Copy _
Workbooks("01 Master Template.xlsm") _
.Sheets("DATA"). _
Range("A2")

'The sourcerange2 and 3 are exactly the same just changed source and output

End Sub
```

Any help appreciated! Let me know if any info can be provided? Thanks!

Comment: `Cells(2, 9).End(xlDown).Address` will be calculating based on ActiveSheet - it should be `Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1").Cells(2, 9).End(xlDown).Address`

Comment: Oh my god I could kiss you! I will be remembering that lesson for sure. Can't thank you enough! Happy holidays!

Comment: To be explicit with @yowE3ks answer, *any time* you use multiple worksheets you should always always always specify the worksheet you expect a Range type variable to be run on. This includes `Range()`, `Cells()`, `Rows` and `Columns`, etc. Otherwise it's going to use the ActiveSheet, whatever that may be. So in your `Sub sourcerange1loop` you need to add the workbook/worksheet before `Cells()` too. (Using a `With` statement could cut down the text needed, but that's up to you)

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne, I think I will make it a habit to set it at the start along the lines of sourcerange1 = Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1") to save some space and make it easier to remember including the workbook on all the references to ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you don't qualify which sheet your `Cells` properties are referring to.

Most of your cases are not affected, because you are just calculating an `Address` of a specific cell, e.g. `Cells(2, 1).Address` which will always return "$A$2" irrespective of which sheet it is looking at.

However you have one statement:

```
Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1").Range( _
Cells(2, 1).Address, Cells(2, 9).End(xlDown).Address).Copy _
Workbooks("01 Master Template.xlsm") _
.Sheets("DATA"). _
Range("A2")
```

in which you are performing an `End(xlDown)` before obtaining the address, and that **will** be affected by which sheet it is referring to, as different sheets will have different rows filled in in column I.

You should always qualify properties such as `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows`, `Columns` so that VBA knows what sheet you are referencing.  So the previously mentioned statement should be:

```
Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1").Range( _
Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1").Cells(2, 1).Address, _
Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1").Cells(2, 9).End(xlDown).Address).Copy _
Workbooks("01 Master Template.xlsm") _
.Sheets("DATA"). _
Range("A2")
```

And that could be simplified to:

```
With Workbooks(DataTool).Sheets("sourcerange1")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 9).End(xlDown)).Copy _
          Workbooks("01 Master Template.xlsm").Sheets("DATA").Range("A2")
End With
```